# Why my break point don't hit when i built my project by pressing CTRL+F5 in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I want to know that when i build my project by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, it never hits the break points that I set in code but when I build my project by clicking on `LOCAL WINDOWS DEBUGGER` , it hits the breakpoints set in code?

I have searched on the internet,I found that this happens because when we build the project by clicking on `LOCAL WINDOWS DEBUGGER`, visual studio attaches a debugger to our built program.

The following are my questions :

**1. Why is there a difference between them ?**
**2. How is the debugger attached to project by visual studio ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is probably mapped to "Start without Debugging" so it does not attach the debugger and only executes your code.

> why there is difference between them

As the names suggest, one attaches the debugger and the other doesn't

> How exactly this debugger is attached to project by visual studio.

May want to look at:
[How does debugging work in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654942/how-does-debugging-work-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2):

On pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, you are asking `Visual Studio` to run the application without the debugger attached( *"Start Without Debugging"*) whereas the `LOCAL WINDOWS DEBUGGER` runs the application with the debugger attached.

> Why is there a difference between them ?

The reason we have this is because it allows us to do two different things in the world of software development. Let us say that I am working on developing an application and I run into various anomalies, **how do I solve it ?**

I debug through my code, find what is going around in my mess and come to the a root cause analysis of my problem.

**What enables me to achieve this ?**

**When there is a debugger attached !** When the debugger is attached, it allows you to set breakpoints in code to have a good understanding of the behavior of your code in run-time. On top of that, it helps us when we use features such as Watch, hover over a variable to observe or edit it's value in runtime. All this is only possible when there is debugger attached to the running application.

**So, what happens when we run it without a debugger ?**

Simple, It doesn't attach the debugger. When you are more interested in the end product that the code runs and gives rather than the intermediate steps and scenarios it encounters, you would select this option.

> How is the debugger attached to project by visual studio ?

I am not sure of that to be honest. I guess you can refer user1451348's answer for that.